# Problem showing part of navigation menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have horizontal navigation menu with lot of list items. I want to display only five items and hide the rest. Then add left and right arrow buttons at the both ends of the navigation menu. On click it shows the next 5 list items.

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 5</a></li>
   <li class="hide"><a href="#">List item 6</a></li>
   <li class="hide"><a href="#">List item 7</a></li>
   <li class="hide"><a href="#">List item 8</a></li>
   <li class="hide"><a href="#">List item 9</a></li>
   <li class="hide"><a href="#">List item 10</a></li>
</ul>
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not clear as to whether you're asking a question about a problem, or asking others to write your code.  Might be helpful if you clarify.  You'll get responses either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it:

HTML code

```
<ul id="list">
   <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 6</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 7</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 8</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 9</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List item 10</a></li>
</ul>
<input type="button" name="prev" value=" prev " />
<input type="button" name="next" value=" next " />
```

JavaScript Code

```
var list = $('#list li');
reset();

function reset () {
    step = 5; // number of list items to show (by removing hidden class)
    current = 0;

    for (i=0; i< list.length; i++) {
        if ( i >= step ) { $(list[i]).addClass('hidden'); }
         else $(list[i]).removeClass('hidden');
    }
}

$('input[name="next"]').live('click', function () {

    current += step;
    threshold = current + step;
    if (threshold > list.length-1+step) { current -= step; threshold = list.length; }
    for (i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if ( (i >= current) && (i < threshold ) ) { $(list[i]).removeClass('hidden'); }
         else $(list[i]).addClass('hidden');
    }
});
$('input[name="prev"]').live('click', function () {
    current -= step;
    threshold = current + step;
    if (current < 0) { reset();  threshold = current + step; 
    }
    for (i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if ( (i >= current) && (i < threshold ) ) { $(list[i]).removeClass('hidden'); }
         else $(list[i]).addClass('hidden');
    } 
});
```